# cutycapt not capturing some webpages

Tags: cutycapt

Am having a problem capturing some websites using cutycapt.

It's not the famous HTTPS issue but seems its usually with sites using CDN for serving their media files for example :

```
preciousmoments.com
tallmenshoes.com
```

Command used is :

`xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 800x600x24" CutyCapt --silent --url=http://domain.com --out=domain.com.png`

Any recommendations for specific command line arguments or version/patch to be used with cutycapt for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
% CutyCapt --url=http://www.tallmenshoes.com --out=t.png --delay=10000
```

on Windows and that seems to work fine.